# How to make tkinter work with macOS python3?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am unable to get rid of this error msg:

```
 File "hpfc.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "/Users/anisha/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I have the python version 3.7.3 and brew list shows `tcl-tk` is installed. I don't understand why it won't work then.

P.S I am very new to python. Also, i do not want to uninstall and reinstall python because it took a lot of time to get it to work the first time around.

Comment: can you try and run `python -m pip install python-tk` and see if that solves it?

Comment: @ItaiBenAmram i did that and this error message appeared: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-tk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-tk

Comment: forwarding you to the official docs of Tk: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html 
follow the steps there, under "Installing Tcl/Tk and Compiling Python"
there's also a github post with this same problem: 
https://gist.github.com/iexa/2ac761bfd96ab78988b76c030d54a5b8

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments - if anyone faces this issue, a fix with a step by step guide is written in this post on GitHub:
[Link to Post](https://gist.github.com/iexa/2ac761bfd96ab78988b76c030d54a5b8) (steps are in the first comment)

Quoting the simplest way of solving this:

> A simple fix on macOS is to uninstall python using `brew unistall python` and then `bew cleanup` before you attempt to reinstall python.